# Replacing Merge in SQL Server with some other code

Tags: sql-server, merge

How can I replace the merge query with some other code in SQL Server 2005 in below code 
to get the same functionality.

```
 alter trigger [Emp_Update_Logging] on [Employee_Test]
  after update
  as


   MERGE INTO dbo.Emp_Log EL
   USING INSERTED I
      ON EL.EID = I.Emp_ID
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET EL.ModifiedDate = getdate()
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT(EID,ModifiedDate)
      VALUES(I.Emp_ID,getdate());

  go
```

Comment: please accept an answer and close out this question.

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to break up the `MERGE` into two operations - an `INSERT` for those rows that don't exist yet, and an `UPDATE` for those rows that do exist already.

Something like this might work:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Emp_Update_Logging] ON [Employee_Test]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
    -- insert those rows from Inserted that don't exist yet
    INSERT INTO dbo.Emp_Log(EID, ModifiedDate)
      SELECT I.Emp_ID, GETDATE()
      FROM Inserted i
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Emp_Log WHERE EID = i.Emp_ID)

    -- update those rows that already exist
    UPDATE dbo.Emp_Log
    SET ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE EXIST (SELECT * FROM dbo.Emp_Log WHERE EID = i.Emp_ID)
```

However, since this is an **UPDATE** trigger, I would argue that you will never have rows that don't exist yet - after all, this trigger only fires when **an EXISTING row is updated** .....

Comment: Without coming up with my own example, this format does not look 100% correct.   In this specific case, there's no harm, because for both an `insert` and an `update`, the example is just updating a timestamp to now.  HOWEVER, we can not use this format if different things are done with the data based on whether it's an `Insert` or an `Update`.  In this answer, the `Insert` adds the missing rows... but the `Update` will update ALL rows, not just the old rows that previously existed.  The newly-inserted rows in step 1 are now a part of the `Where exists` clause in step 2.

Comment: You can not necessarily use the fact that this is an `Update` trigger to eliminate the `Update` statement.  The trigger is on `table  [Employee_Test]`, but the code is updating or inserting to `table dbo.Emp_Log`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do the `UPDATE` first, then do the `INSERT`.

For a general generic solution for replacing `Merge` with some other SQL code, Marc's answer does not look 100% correct.

In his specific answer, there's no harm, because for both an `insert` and an `update`, the example is just updating a timestamp to now.  HOWEVER, we can not use this format if different things are done with the data based on whether it's an `Insert` or an `Update`. In this answer, the `Insert` adds the missing rows... but the `Update` will update ALL rows, not just the old rows that previously existed.

The newly-inserted rows in step 1 are now a part of the `Where Exists` clause in step 2.

The simple solution to the issue I just raised in this answer would be to do the `UPDATE` first, then do the `INSERT`.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Emp_Update_Logging] ON [Employee_Test]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS

    -- update those rows that already exist
    UPDATE dbo.Emp_Log
    SET ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE EXIST (SELECT * FROM dbo.Emp_Log WHERE EID = i.Emp_ID)

    -- insert those rows from Inserted that don't exist yet
    INSERT INTO dbo.Emp_Log(EID, ModifiedDate)
      SELECT I.Emp_ID, GETDATE()
      FROM Inserted i
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Emp_Log WHERE EID = i.Emp_ID)
```

Also... I'm not a big fan of the `Where EXIST / NOT EXIST` subclauses.  In some cases it would be beneficial to `left join` with `dbo.Emp_Log` and add to your `where` clause to check for a value to be `NULL` or not.